# Can Google Cloud Vision return more language of label?

Tags: php, google-api, google-cloud-vision

I tried sample of Google Vision API (PHP)

```
# includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;

# instantiates a client
$imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

# the name of the image file to annotate
$fileName = 'test/data/wakeupcat.jpg';

# prepare the image to be annotated
$image = file_get_contents($fileName);

# performs label detection on the image file
$response = $imageAnnotator->labelDetection($image);
$labels = $response->getLabelAnnotations();

if ($labels) {
    echo("Labels:" . PHP_EOL);
    foreach ($labels as $label) {
        echo($label->getDescription() . PHP_EOL);
    }
} else {
    echo('No label found' . PHP_EOL);
}
```

I can get label of objects in image, its awesome, but label is English language. Can I config API return other language or multi language?

P/S: Sorry for my bad English :(

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could try to translate it using another API, such as:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-translate

Kind regards